# Conditionally replacing an input field when submitting a form

Tags: form, coffeescript

I just wrote this, and cleaned it up as much as I could. A couple things worry me:

- I change the scope of `$(this)` twice (and apparently don't know how to use `=>`)
- The big `if if/else` statement. Is there a better way to write that?

Also, it's an IIFE, and the big identing makes the `)()` at the end look out of place.

```
  emptyTagFieldsOnDeletion = (->
    $('form.simple_form').submit ->
      $form = $(this)
      $form.find('.fake-input').each ->
        $fakeInput = $(this)
        $ulId = $fakeInput.closest('ul').attr('id')
        if $fakeInput.children('li').length is 1
          $fakeInput.children().remove()
          if $ulId is 'primary_diagnosis_select'
            $fakeInput.append emptyListArrayHTML('primary_icd9_codes')
          else if $ulId is 'secondary_diagnosis_select'
            $fakeInput.append emptyListArrayHTML('secondary_icd9_codes')
          else
            $fakeInput.append emptyListArrayHTML('med_names')
  )()
```

For reference, the `emptyListArrayHTML` method looks like this:

```
emptyListArrayHTML = (list_type)->
  "<input type='text' name='#{nameWithListType(list_type)}' value=''>"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mention the changes in scope as though they're a problem. But you actually want them here, since that's how jQuery operates, and using `=>` would be counterproductive. Anyway here are some notes

1. CoffeeScript has a `do` keyword for IIFEs. So `do -> ...` is equivalent to `(-> ...)()` without the need for all those parentheses
2. It seems your IIFE isn't returning something you'll need later; it's just encapsulating some code. In that case, don't bother giving it a name. Just invoke it.
3. You don't need to cache `$form` - you only use it once
4. Don't call the UL id `$ulId` - that is, don't use a `$` in the name. It's not a jQuery object, it's just a string
5. You can use a `switch` statement instead of the `if... else`, which helps a bit (but read on for a better solution)

Here's the code with these tweaks:

```
do ->
  $('form.simple_form').submit ->
    $(this).find('.fake-input').each ->   # don't bother caching $form
      $fakeInput = $ this
      return unless $fakeInput.children().length is 1 # return early instead of a big if-block

      $fakeInput.empty()

      switch $fakeInput.closest('ul').attr('id')
        when 'primary_diagnosis_select'
          $fakeInput.append emptyListArrayHTML('primary_icd9_codes')
        when 'secondary_diagnosis_select'
          $fakeInput.append emptyListArrayHTML('secondary_icd9_codes')
        else
          $fakeInput.append emptyListArrayHTML('med_names')
```

However, I'd make the relationships explicit in the markup. For instance, give the UL element a `data-codes` attribute or something:

```
<ul id="primary_diagnosis_select" data-codes="primary_icd9_codes">
...
<ul id="secondary_diagnosis_select" data-codes="secondary_icd9_codes">
...
<ul id="something_else"> <!-- no data-codes for this one; defaults to "med_names" in the CoffeeScript code -->
```

Then you can shorten the code like so:

```
do ->
  $('form.simple_form').submit ->
    $(this).find('.fake-input').each ->
      $fakeInput = $ this
      return unless $fakeInput.children().length is 1
      $fakeInput.empty()
      codes = $fakeInput.closest('ul').data("codes") or "med_names"
      $fakeInput.append emptyListArrayHTML(codes)
```

Now the CoffeeScript handles only logic while the data and relationships are declared in the markup. You can add the single line from `emptyListArrayHTML` back into the function with complicating things too much, though.

p.s. CoffeeScript also has a triple-quote Python-like heredoc syntax, if you want to use double quotes in a string without escaping them. So your `emptyListArrayHTML` function could be written as

```
emptyListArrayHTML = (list_type) ->
  """<input type="text" name="#{nameWithListType list_type}" value="">"""
```

It looks a little strange at first (and the syntax highlighting is messed up here), but I like to use it, because I prefer to always use double quotes for HTML attributes (just personal preference).

Comment: Yep. All great suggestions. Just what I was looking for! Thanks.